# Backbone Node put delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backbone.js, put

I've created this app using Backbone, Node, MongoDB and Express to learn. The POST requests work just fine, but for some reason the PUT and DELETE requests are sent with an enormous delay and they seem to be rejected. I've checked and re-checked and nothing seems to be wrong, according to the console, the requests are what I expect them to be.

Here's my middleware code, including method-override:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(methodOverride()); //so we can receive DELETE requests
```

Here are the server functions that handle the PUT and DELETE respectively:

```
router.put('/api/dogs/:id', function(req, res) {
    mongo.db()
        .collection('dogs')
        .update({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, function (err) {
            if (err) {throw err;}
        });
});

router.delete('/api/dogs/:id', function(req, res) {
  mongo.db()
    .collection('dogs')
    .remove({_id: req.params.id}, function (err) {
      if (err) {throw err;}
    });
});
```

And the view functions that make the PUT and DELETE requests respectively, just in case:

```
close: function (ev) {
            var $input = $(ev.target);
            var value = $input.val().trim(); //we trim the value of the input
            var data = {};
            data[$input.attr('name')] = value;
            this.model.set(data);
            this.model.save();
        },

clear: function () {
            this.model.destroy();
        }
```

Can anybody see what's wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own question. In case anyone was wondering, what needed to be done was to convert the id taken from req.params and convert into an ObjectId, and also remove the _id from the item sent.

```
var id = new mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id);

var dog = req.body;
delete( dog._id );
```

Thanks anyway!